# Set a Fixed shipping price based on product attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shipping

Using Magento 1.9. I was not able to find an extension that does this as far as i can tell, and i cannot set this up using the promotion rules.

I want to setup 4 different fixed shipping rates, free, 50, 100, 150, but based on the largest item in my cart. These are based on product size. For example 4 different sizes light, small, medium and large, i setup all products to have this attribute and set which size they are. I would like the fixed rate shipping option to be based on the largest item in the cart. So if 2 small items and one large item are in the cart the fixed rate is still only 150. If only light items are in the cart you get free shipping.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with **table rates** based on weight:

- 0-2 kg - light - FREE
- 2-5 kg - small - 50
- 5-7 kg - medium - 100
- 7 kg and above - large - 150

See this article for instructions how to set **Magento table rates** for shipping: http://www.sitepoint.com/set-up-table-rate-shipping-in-magento/

Comment: I think i can make this work and it should work 90% of the time, the only issue here is if someone orders x amount of small items weight limit could exceed into the medium rate, so i have to setup weight range accordingly. But works for now. Thanks!